# Was Nikki Haley disqualified from a beauty pageant because of race?

Tags: united-states, racism

2024 Republican Presidential candidate Nikki Haley just said [this](https://x.com/collinrugg/status/1749224498870808700?s=46&t=D1s1R_Ft6YRO_vPb8S9JRg) to NBC News:

> If you want to know what it was like growing up, **I was disqualified from a beauty pageant because I wasn’t white or Black because they didn’t know where to put me**.  So look, I know the hardships, the pain that comes with racism.

My question is, is it true that Nikki Haley was disqualified from a beauty pageant because she was neither white nor black?

Comment: It might be worth noting that she claims this happened when she was 5 years old which would have been around 1977 which could make it harder to track down.

Comment: @njuffa Well, were there racially segregated child beauty pageants in South Carolina in 1977?

Comment: The question would be better if it pointed to Haleys' more complete statements what happened, such as "Republican presidential candidate Nikki Haley shares why she was disqualified from a beauty pageant" at https://www.wmur.com/article/nikki-haley-beauty-pageant-story/45853372, where Haley explains that the kiddie pageant had "a white queen and a black queen" and the pageant organizers told her parents they would have to disqualify both Haley and her sister because parents of children in either category would get mad. But the pageant did let 5-year-old Haley sing her song.

Answer (score 11):

The full claim is as follows:

> At a kiddie beauty pageant, Haley and her sister were ushered off the stage because they were weren't black or white − fitting neither of the local prize categories.

This requires journalistic research but it's not implausible on its face.

Before 1968, Miss America did not accept black applicants, although Native Americans and Asians were allowed to participate by the 1950s.<sup>1</sup> In early 20th century Miss America competitions, during the musical part of the pageant, black women appeared as slaves in the back of the stage while the white contestants sang plantation songs.<sup>2</sup>

In response to this, two ethnically segregated pageant systems arose in the 1950s: Miss Indian America and Miss Chinatown USA.<sup>3</sup>  Black women did not have a national system; beauty pageants were generally associated with segregated high schools and HBCUs.<sup>4</sup>

The first black contestant in Miss America appeared in 1970, and the first winner was not until 1983. It's at least plausible that during this transitional period, local child beauty pageants may have still been perceived as places where beauty was evaluated racially. However, that's far from a proof that this incident happened the way Haley recalls it.

<sup>1</sup> Valerie Felita Kinloch, [The Rhetoric of Black Bodies](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1057/9781403981820_5) (2004)
<sup>2</sup> [The Most Beautiful Girl in the World:
Beauty Pageants and National Identity](https://www.ucpress.edu/book/9780520217911/the-most-beautiful-girl-in-the-world) (1999)
<sup>3</sup> [Beauty, Bodies, and Boundaries: Pageants, Race and U.S. National Identity](https://www.proquest.com/docview/849734456?) (2010)
<sup>4</sup> [Black Beauties: African American Pageant Queens in the Segregated South](https://www.hoopladigital.com/title/12796570) (2020)

---

**Edit**: I've been asked to add a source on the idea that Haley would have confused Southerners in the 1970s by being neither white nor black. This common reaction is well-represented in period fiction, but I'm not sure what non-fiction citation to use as evidence. Until someone suggests one, I recommend the film [*Mississippi Masala*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mississippi_Masala) (1991).

Comment: The claim suggests that the pageant allowed white and blacks but not her

Comment: @JoeW The suggestion is that there were white pageants who would not admit her because they didn't think she was white, and black pageants who didn't think she was black. Easy enough to believe.

Comment: @DJClayworth Just because it is believable doesn't mean we don't need evidence to show that it actually happened.

Comment: @JoeW The answer agrees with you.

Comment: @DJClayworth The answer doesn't seem to provide any evidence that she was disqualified from a beauty pageant, just suggests that it was possible. At least that is what I get from the answer. I don't see anything that either confirms or denies the claim at all in the answer. Answers that just say it is or isn't possible shouldn't be acceptable on this site.

Comment: @JoeW the answer very clearly marks itself as a partial answer: *"This requires journalistic research but it's not implausible on its face"*. Partial answers have been discussed on meta ([example](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/389/10630), [another](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/3227)) and the consensus appears to be that they're useful and acceptable, so long as they're relevant, referenced, and up front about their limitations (like this one is)

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 This site is for confirming or debunking a claim, just stating that it is possible is of no value as it leaves the question up in the air if the claim is actually true or not. It is easily possible that an answer could state that the claim if possible but in reality the claim is actually incorrect.

Comment: @JoeW You can vote it down if you like. But plenty of us think it's useful. If you want to argue the usefulness of partial answers I suggest Meta, although it's already been discussed there. Or try chat.

Comment: If you read the most recent comments on the question it becomes clear this is exactly what is claimed to have happened. So we have a detailed claim by Haley, which multiple sources agree is plausible and fairly common for the time. Since it's unlikely that media of the time would have covered "five year old excluded from beauty pageant" we are forced to take Haley at her word or not, as we please. Plenty of real things happened to me in my childhood that would be considered "unverifiable" on this site.

Comment: @DJClayworth I just don’t understand how an answer that just says something is possible and makes no attempt to actually address it the claim is valid or not is acceptable.

Comment: I believe the meta links above demonstrate that we have collectively decided to welcome any sort of objective knowledge contribution as long as it helps people render judgment on the question. I guess I did not help you, but it seems I helped some other people, so it turned out ok.

Comment: @JoeW If it was impossible to be true that would be useful information. So if it is not impossible (and in fact quite likely) that is also useful information. In fact from your very first comment here you seemed to think  such a thing was impossible and you made fun of the idea. Now this answer has shown you that it might have happened, and happened fairly frequently. So you have better information than you did before, making this a helpful answer. But please, if you want to talk more please go to chat. This has got far beyond the purpose of improving the answer.

Comment: @JoeW Take it to chat please.

Comment: @DJClayworth I posted a meta question over this and yet again it you don’t want this conversation to continue stop pinging me with replies and just accept that we are not going to agree.

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8
  Here we go again https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5026/are-answers-saying-a-claim-is-possible-allowed